# JavaScript - window.open not working on Firefox mobile iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox

The following function which uses window.open doesn't work in Firefox mobile for iOS. Any ideas why?

https://jsfiddle.net/3z6ygk8w/

```
<button onclick="mapsSelector('47.91', '-122.02')">
Test
</button>

<script>
function mapsSelector(locationLatitude, locationLongitude) {
    if /* if we're on iOS, open in Apple Maps */
        ((navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) || 
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1) || 
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1))
        window.open("maps://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+locationLatitude+","+locationLongitude+"&amp;ll=");
    else /* else use Google */
        window.open("https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+locationLatitude+","+locationLongitude+"&amp;ll=");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Firefox 76 has changed how it responds to "features" specified in ```window.open() ``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#toolbar_and_ui_parts_features

Comment: I read the documentation but I'm struggling to get it to work... what exactly needs to be different in the window.open() syntax? Thanks for your help!